# Apartment gem: How to enable user to delete their subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the Apartment gem in Rails 4.2. How could I enable the user to destroy their whole subdomain account?

I know how to destroy an individual user, but how could I enable the admin to destroy their subdomain also?

In the create action I have:

```
  Apartment::Tenant.create(@account.subdomain)
  Apartment::Tenant.switch(@account.subdomain)
```

So could I do e.g. Apartment::Tenant.destroy in a destroy action?

Answer (score 1):

There are no delete/destroy methods for Aparment, use this:

```
Apartment::Tenant.drop("schema_name")
```